# Como mostrar en un PrintPreviewDialog un pdf tipo iText.Layout.Document creado con iText7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itext, itextpdf

Trabajo en un proyecto el cual genera como resultado final un archivo pdf que es creado con iText7, pero quiero mostrarlo al usuario en un PrintPreviewDialog para que revise los resultados antes de utilizar el archivo pdf.

Esta es una idea de lo que intento hacer:

```
public void GeneracionPdf()
{
    PageSize TipoHoja = PageSize.LETTER;
    float AnchoEfectivoHoja;
    PdfWriter NombreArchivo = new PdfWriter(rutaExportacionPDF);
    PdfDocument ArchivoPdf = new PdfDocument(NombreArchivo);
    Document ContenidoDocumento = new Document(ArchivoPdf, TipoHoja);
    
    ContenidoDocumento.SetMargins(75, 35, 50, 35);

    AnchoEfectivoHoja = ContenidoDocumento.GetPageEffectiveArea(TipoHoja).GetWidth();
    {
        /*........................                                  
        PROCESO DE CARGA DE CONTENIDO DE PDF.                   
        ...........................*/
    }
            
    bmp = new Bitmap(ContenidoDocumento);
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    ContenidoDocumento.Close();             
}       
    Bitmap bmp;
            
private void PrintDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
}
```

La situación es como convertir de iText.Layout.Document a un formato que pueda ser mostrado en el PrintPreviewDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el **componente WebBrowser**. Selecciona este componente en la **caja de herramientas** y arrástralo hacia tu formulario. Posteriormente añade este código después que el **pdf** sea generado:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"D:\Documentación\MiPDF.pdf");
```

De esta forma le indicamos al **webBrowser** que cargue el **fichero pdf** a partir de una ruta pasada como parámetro. Desde aquí incluso podrás hacer otras operaciones tales como imprimir, zoom y muchas otras.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, funciono a la perfección.