¿Como puedo visualizar un archivo sin utilizar el pdf reader en c#?
Tengo que crear un OCR en Windows Form C# pero no he encontrado informacion de como puedo visualizar los documentos adjuntos sin utilizar un lector de pdf o que sea externo.

Bienvenido, revisar [ask], saludos.

No entiendo la pregunta.. y como esperas visualzarlo???

Revisa este enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/501540/como-mostrar-en-un-printpreviewdialog-un-pdf-tipo-itext-layout-document-creado-c/502006#502006

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
