COMO VISUALIZAR UN PDF EN UN FORM DE C# EN VISUAL STUDIO 2022
USE VARIAS LIBRERIAS Y HASTA EL COM DE ADOBE ACROBAT PERO NO SE PUEDE CARGAR LOS PDF, NO SE SI ES POR LA VERSION DE MI VISUAL O POR LA ANTIGUEDAD DE MI CONTROLADORES, SOLO QUIERO VISUALIZAR EL PDF EXTERNO PARA LUEGO ENVIARLO A IMPRIMIR, SEGUN LAS CONSULTAS DEL USUARIO


Que versión de .net ??

Cómo es tu código y cómo estás configurando el proyecto? Según esta publicación, es bastante fácil usar COM con Acrobat.

Revisa esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/501540/como-mostrar-en-un-printpreviewdialog-un-pdf-tipo-itext-layout-document-creado-c/502006#502006

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
